# Python asyncio difference between loop.create_task and asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

What is the pythonic way to push a coroutine onto an event thread from outside of the event thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated info:**

Starting from Python 3.7 high-level function `asyncio.create_task(coro)` [was added](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) and can be used instead of both `asyncio.ensure_future` and `loop.create_task` to create tasks.

Python documentation [refers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) to `asyncio.create_task(coro)` as to "preferred way for creating new Tasks".

**Original answer:**

Just to be clear: usually asyncio runs in single thread. Concurrency provided not by threads, but by using single event loop for running different coroutines.

If you want to submit coroutine being run concurrently without waiting for it's result you should create [task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) using `asyncio.ensure_future` ([difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415477/1113207) from `create_task`).

But if your app using multiple threads and you want to submit coroutine being run from one thread to event loop running in another thread, you should use `run_coroutine_threadsafe`. Here's nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33099589/1113207) of running event loop in another thread and submiting coroutine to in from main thread.

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, maybe its better to update your answer since now `asyncio.create_task(coro)` is possible.

Comment: @LeonardoRick thanks for noticing! Updated!

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov Please add source for "from Python 3.7 `asyncio.create_task(coro)` should be used"